# Hadoop mkdir and ls commands

Tags: hadoop

I did fresh setup of hadoop2.9.

To create a directory, I tried:

```
> hadoop fs -mkdir test 
mkdir: 'test': No such file or directory
```

To list its content, I tried:

```
> hadoop fs -ls/ 
not listing directories or files
```

Please help me to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just setup hadoop, HDFS is empty. make some file and directories like below with a full path:

`hadoop fs -mkdir /test`

Answer (score 0):

Without a fully qualified path, you are required to make a user folder first

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/$(whoami)
hdfs dfs -chown -R $(whoami)  /user/$(whoami)
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 750  /user/$(whoami)
```

Then, the first command will work so will `put` and `ls` without an otherwise fully qualified path

Answer (score 0):

For listing we can use

hadoop fs -mkdir /

e.g

hadoop fs -mkdir /hadoop/schema/test

For listing if its a file we can access
hadoop fs -cat /

e.g

hadoop fs -cat /hadoop/schema/test.txt